# Typo in the "honeypot question" post notice text

Tags: bug, status-completed, spelling, post-notices

The "honeypot question" post notice contains a typo:

[image: screenshot or it didn't happen]

It should say "why you're recommending it as a solution" instead.

Comment: or "why you're recommending it as a solution" of course :)

Comment: @ChrisF Yeah, or that. :)

Comment: Spelling: ur doing it wrong!

Comment: "why *you've recommended* it as a solution"

Comment: @slugster Not sure about that... it'd be out of sync with the rest of the sentence. To EL&U! :)

Comment: Wow, glad the name of that post notice changed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in our next deploy.

Answer (score 3):

As the person [who originally suggested the honeypot notice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/106374/revisions), I'll take the blame for the typo: it should be "why you're *recommending* it."

That'll teach me to copy and paste the original moderator notice we use on Programmers instead of typing it out.